# $\tau$ and grouping of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

From Prime Number Theorem and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html) we can state $$\frac{p_n}{\bar{p}}\sim 2$$ or $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{np_n}{(p_1 + \dots +p_n)} = 2$$

If we then look at the fluctuations in the graph of $$f(n) = \frac{np_n}{(p_1 + \dots +p_n)}$$ so that $$g(n) = \left|\space f(n) - f(n-1)\right|$$ we get the following plot[image]

Now this plot is interesting to me for two reasons:

- it seems to divide the prime numbers into groups that tend to follow a certain function
- the graphs of each of those functions seem to shift on the x-axis by a factor of $\tau$ (or $2\pi$).

I'm no mathematician, so I'd like to know if these findings correspond to any known theorems or if they have any truth or significance at all.

(This is related to my earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409219/does-anyone-recognize-this-graph) on this subject)

**Extra**
Here is the similar looking graph for the difference between the error terms of $p_n \sim n\log(n)$ for $n$ and $n-1$.

[image: second graph]

Comment: You should probably make mention of your earlier variant of this question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409219/does-anyone-recognize-this-graph -- they're not exact duplicates, but they're *very* closely related.

Comment: A very aesthetic picture indeed!

Comment: I have never seen this limit. So, there is a very nice way to approximate the SUM of the first $n$ primes. Is anything known about the error term ?

Comment: Reading the equation in the form $$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n p_j}{n}\approx \frac{p_n}{2}$$ allows the interpretation : The average of the first $n$ prime numbers if about the half of the $n-th$ prime number, so in some sense, the primes are symmetric distributed around the half of the $n-th$ prime.

Comment: The inequality $f(10^8)>2.05$ shows how slow the function tends to $2$.

Comment: @Peter you could add those comments as an answer (it is a good hint / insight) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similar looking graph when I plotted the difference between the error terms of $p_n \sim n\log(n)$ for $n$ and $n-1$. From this I got a better understanding of the graph, because here we can say
$$f(n) = \left|n\log n - p_n - (n-1)\log(n-1)+p_{n-1}\right|$$
$$= \left|\log(n^n) - \log((n-1)^{n-1}) - g\right|$$
where $g$ is the prime gap between $p_n$ and $p_{n-1}$. We can then further simplify
$$f(n)= \left|\log\left(\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}\right) - g\right|$$
and because 
$$\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}} \sim en$$ 
we can say 
$$f(n) \approx \left|\log(en) - g\right|$$
It's now easy to see why this graph has the shape that it has. It's essentially a bunch of logarithmic functions that are shifted vertically by an amount of $g$. The fishnet-like appearance comes from the absolute brackets in the function, that reflect the negative values over the x-axis.

Now back to the original graph, which is a similar graph, but has a downward slope. If we look at Barry's observations on the function of the graph and take out the error terms
$$\Delta(n) \approx \frac{2}{n} \left|{g\over\log n}-1\right|$$
we can then bring that down to
$$\Delta(n) \approx \frac{2}{n\log n} \left|g-\log n \right|$$

Now we have a similar function to that of the other graph, where the first term is responsible for the downward slope, $\log n$ for the logarithmic functions and $g$ for the vertical shift of these functions. Again the absolute brackets make the fishnet-like appearance.

Comment: @BarryCipra I added the graph to the original question.

Comment: @BarryCipra I just added it, because of your comment :)

Comment: Oh, so that's how I managed to miss it!  Well, thank you for adding it.

Comment: I'm still perplexed by the regularity of the spikes.  What do you get if you simply graph the function $g(n)=g_n=p_n-p_{n-1}$?

Comment: @BarryCipra The regularity of the spikes comes from the regularity of the prime gaps. If you plot the prime gaps, you'll get a graph with horizontal lines on y=2, y=4, y=6, etc.

Comment: Ah yes, I (finally!) see what's going on:  the spikes (for your new graph) occur when $\log n$ is close to an *odd* integer.  That's because what you're graphing is approximately $|log n-(gn-1)|$, where the gap between primes $gn$ is *even*.

Answer (score 1):

There is something worth explaining in the regularity of the fishnet pattern with the dangling spikes in the OP's graph.  I don't know what the explanation is, but I thought it'd be worth writing up some observations, in hopes that someone with keener analytic eyes than mine will pick up where I leave off.

Let me begin with a bit of notation.  Since the OP is interested in the *ratio* of the $n$th prime to the average of the first $n$ primes, let's write

$$R_n={np_n\over p_1+\cdots+p_n}$$

The OP is graphing the function

$$\Delta(n)=|R_n-R_{n-1}|$$

I'm using $\Delta$ instead of $g$ for this function because I want to use $g$ to denote the *gap* between primes.  It's possible to rewrite $R_{n-1}$ in terms of $n$, $R_n$, $p_n$ and $g_n=p_n-p_{n-1}$.  The result is

$$\Delta(n)={R_n\over|n-R_n|}\left|{(n-1)g_n\over p_n}-(R_n-1) \right|$$

This formula has a nicer appearance if we dispense with the subscript (but, of course, keeping in mind that it's really there):

$$\Delta(n)={R\over|n-R|}\left|{(n-1)g\over p}-(R-1) \right|$$

Let's now recall that the ratio $R_n$ tends to $2$ as $n\to\infty$, so we can write $R=2+\epsilon$, with the understanding that $\epsilon=\epsilon_n\to0$.  This gives

$$\Delta(n)={2+\epsilon\over|n-2-\epsilon|}\left|{(n-1)g\over p}-1-\epsilon \right|$$

Since the graph uses a logarithmic vertical scale, it makes sense to take logs here.  If we also do a little approximating, we have

$$\begin{align}
\log(\Delta(n))&=\log(2+\epsilon)-\log|n-2-\epsilon|+\log\left|{(n-1)g\over p}-1-\epsilon \right|\\
&\approx\log2-\log n+ \log\left|{(n-1)g\over p}-1-\epsilon \right|
\end{align}$$

Now the first two terms here, $\log2-\log n$, accord with the overall downward slope of the graph. (Actually, as Peter has observed, $\epsilon$ takes its time getting small, so we should probably keep it in the $\log(2+\epsilon)$.  But its local effect is merely to shift the entire graph up or down.)  The fuzziness, the fishnet, and the spikes, must be coming from the third term.

Note that $p=p_n\approx n\log n$, so we can write

$${(n-1)g\over p}-1-\epsilon={g\over\log n}-1-\epsilon'$$

where $\epsilon'=\epsilon_n'$ now incorporates the errors of two approximations.  Now with some regularity, the gap between primes is fairly small, e.g., $g=2$ for the occasional twin primes, in which case the third term contributes next to nothing.  I think that goes a long way toward explaining the fairly thick fuzz near the top of the graph.

Furthermore, since the average gap between primes is roughly $\log n$, we can expect the third term to occasionally be the log of a small number, which produces points well below the fuzz.  But why the pattern is so regular still seems mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the approximation in the way :

$$\large \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n p_j}{n}\approx \frac{p_n}{2}$$

allows the interesting interpretation : The arithmetic mean of the first $n$ primes is about the half of the $n-th$ prime, so in some sense, the first $n$
primes are symmetrically distributed around the half of the $n-th$ prime.

Note, that the function is converging very slowly. This can be seen from
$$f(10^8)>2.05$$

The local maxima upto the probable global maximum of $f$ are shown by the
following PARI/GP-program:

```
? maxi=0;s=0;t=1;for(n=1,10^8,merk=s;t=nextprime(t+1);s=s+t;if(n*t/s>maxi,maxi=n
*t/s;print(n,"   ",t,"   ",s,"    ",n*t/s,"   ",1.0*n*t/s)))

1   2   2    1   1.000000000000000000000000000
2   3   5    6/5   1.200000000000000000000000000
3   5   10    3/2   1.500000000000000000000000000
4   7   17    28/17   1.647058823529411764705882353
5   11   28    55/28   1.964285714285714285714285714
7   17   58    119/58   2.051724137931034482758620690
9   23   100    207/100   2.070000000000000000000000000
10   29   129    290/129   2.248062015503875968992248062
12   37   197    444/197   2.253807106598984771573604061
17   59   440    1003/440   2.279545454545454545454545455
25   97   1060    485/212   2.287735849056603773584905660
31   127   1720    3937/1720   2.288953488372093023255813954
35   149   2276    5215/2276   2.291300527240773286467486819
48   223   4661    10704/4661   2.296502896374168633340484875
```

I do not know a theorem related to $f(n)$. And I also do not know if there
is an efficient method to calculate the sum of the first $n$ primes. 
It would be interesting to know at which point the function gets smaller
than $2.01$. In OEIS , I found the sum of the first $10^{13}$ primes :
It is $1,593,061,976,858,155,930,556,059,673$. The $10^{13}-th$ prime 
is $323,780,508,946,331$, so $f(10^{13})>2.03$

Finally, after finding the necessary data for $10^{20}$, I found the
amazing result showing $f(10^{20})>2.02$

```
? print(n,"  ",t,"   ",s,"    ",n*t/s*1.0)
2220819602560918840  99999999999999999989       109778913483063648128485839045703833
541    2.022992879141165878001455078
```

Comment: See also : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html , which gives the approximation $\sum_{j=1}^n\ p_j\approx \frac{n^2\ ln(n)}{2}$, which together with the approximation $p_n\approx n\ ln(n)$ leads to $\large \frac{p_n}{\sum_{j=1}^n p_j}\approx \frac{2}{n}$

Comment: The error-term seems to be approximately $\frac{1}{ln(n)}$, so $f(n)\approx 2+\frac{1}{ln(n)}$. If this is true, $f(e^{100})\approx 2.01$ , so $f(2.7\times 10^{43}) \approx 2.01$

Comment: Interesting stuff. I was aware of a few theorems that relate to $f(n)$. See also the answer to an earlier question by me on this subject:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405710/is-lim-n-to-infty-fracnp-n-sum-i-1n-p-i-2-true. My question this time however is more about $g(n)$ and the graph it plots. Where does the pattern come from and does it indeed relate to $\tau$?